# Datarow value from dictionary objects in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new in MVC and struggling to use below code in controller.

```
List<DataRow> Qd = new List<DataRow>();
Qd = new List<DataRow>(dt.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(r => r.DataRow));
```

When I am compiling getting error:

> 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'DataRow' and
>   no extension method 'DataRow' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?).

I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
        List<DataRow> Qd = new List<DataRow>();
        Qd = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
```

Or simply

```
        List<DataRow> Qd = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
```

Sample code:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("PrinterList");

        foreach (string installedPrinter in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(installedPrinter);
        }


        List<DataRow> Qd = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
```

Comment: @ronibd for me it is working properly. it should work. check properly whether ur datatable is not null.

Comment: Hi Oli, Sorry I forgot to mention that I am getting dt value from dictionary and in an array format. Not straight from the table. Do you think this is the reason I am getting the problem. Also, dont know how to fix this. Please help me to solve the problem. Many thanks

Comment: My dt code is - List<DataRow> dt = new List<DataRow>();
dt = Prtfunc(SCode, gCode, gDB, gRep); I am getting all the parameter value perfectly.

Comment: what is the return value of this function? `Prtfunc(SCode, gCode, gDB, gRep)`

Comment: Returning value is {System.Data.DataRow} and in ItemArray, all the value I am getting

Comment: you are already getting in Array of DataRow.. why you want to convert DataTable and DataRow?? Cant you just apply `.ToList()` to `Prtfunc`

Comment: Yes I can, if its work, I have added .ToList() end of Prtfunc and used your code, but getting same error

Comment: `List<DataRow> Qd = Prtfunc(SCode, gCode, gDB, gRep).ToList();`